# How can I display a message to user showing progress of transfer?

Tags: networking, network-programming

i have to transfer a file from one system to another but i want to display a message to user showing progress of transfer. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Unix/Linux, you have a easy way, RSYNC.

```
rsync -chavz --partial --progress --stats source_files remotehost.domain:target_dir
```

Where:

```
--checksum             -c              -- skip based on checksums, not mod-time & size                                                                                                                   
--human-readable       -h              -- output numbers in a human-readable format                                                                                                                      
--archive              -a              -- archive mode; same as -rlptgoD (no -H)                                                                                        
--verbose              -v              -- increase verbosity                                                                                                                                             
--compress             -z              -- compress file data during the transfer                                                                                
--partial                              -- keep partially transferred files                                                                                                                               
--progress                             -- show progress during transfer                                                     
--stats                                -- give some file-transfer stats
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [scp](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch07_05.htm) with **--with-scp-stats** flag